# BlackBerry Subscription Payment API

Tags: blackberry, java-me, payment, subscription

I want to submit my first subscription based application to AppWorld, however, I have some questions regarding how this works since we cannot find this in the documentation or forum.

All questions are based on the following:
- Subscription application for 30 days and a certain price (so not a subscription digital good)
- When the user buys the app he/she can use it for 30 days

The questions:

1. What happens when the 30 days are over? If the users does not continue the subscription, will AppWorld remove the app from the users phone or will the app stay installed?
2. If AppWorld does not remove the app, how can we check whether the user is still subscribed to using the application? We tried to list all purchases using the payment API and see whether the app is listed, though the purchases are only for digital good (bought within the application).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

The [Payment Service documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=Payment%20Service) will help you

Comment: I have already seen that link, it only describes how to create a subscription digital good. But it never tells whether when the user starts with a subscription product AppWorld will remove/disable the product if the subscription is stopped.